# Negative lookahead doesn't behave as expected

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

Trying to use regex to parse arguments from a string: `"-a 1 -b -5.1"`.

Output should have 2 flags with values: flag `a` with value `1`, `b` with `-5.1`.

When I try `(-(?<flag>[a-zA-Z])(?<value> .+)?(?!-[a-zA-Z]))*` regular expression, it returns only flag `a` with value `1 -b -5.1`.

Why doesn't it stop at `-b`?

Comment: Why not split on space ` ` (into `{"-a", "1", "-b", "-5.1"}`) and then treat even items as names while odd as values?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Just a guess, values might contain spaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tempered Greedy Token - What is different about placing the dot before the negative lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)

Comment: @Sweeper: if value can *contain space* we have an *ambiguity*: `-a 1 -b 5.1` can be either `[{"-a", "1 -b 5.1"}]` or `[{"-a", "1"},  {"-b", "5.1"}]`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Judging from OP's attempt of regex, whenever `-[a-zA-Z]` is seen, that will be the start of a new flag.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko In my case, flag can be without value. That's why taking even items wouldn't work. And, as @Sweeper, mentioned `-b` should be treated as a start of new flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make `(?<value> .+)` lazy and turn the negative lookahead into a positive lookahead.

Here is my try:

```
-(?<flag>[a-zA-Z]) (?<value>.+?)(?=$| -[a-zA-Z])
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rNB6TR/1)

Explanation:

You are probably wondering why a positive lookahead is used instead of a negative one. This is because `+?` will stop matching whenever the thing after it matches. This is why we look ahead to find `$| -[a-zA-Z]` and if we do find one, `+?` stops matching!

I have also moved a space character outside of the `value` group. I assume you don't want the value to contain spaces?

Comment: only problem is that it doesn't work for flags without values. For example, for `-a -b -c -d` this regex will return 2 matches: `-a -b` `-c -d`. While it should be `-a` `-b` `-c` `-d`

Comment: `-(?<flag>[a-zA-Z])( (?<value>.+?))??(?=$| -[a-zA-Z])` will correctly parse flags without values

Comment: @RomanGudkov Right. You didn't mention that in the question, so I didn't notice. So problem solved now?

Comment: You are right, I didn't mention this originally - wanted to keep it short. Decided to add a comment for those who might have similar additional requirement. Solved now.